# Validate multiple nested attributes associated models for equality before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-activerecord, nested-attributes

I have a mediaserver written in rails which allows users to upload images and categorize them.
I am now making the moodboard functionality which is rather complex.

To start we have a `Template` model. This `Template` model has_many `TemplateBlocks`.
A `TemplateBlock` has the properties `width`, `height`, `top`, `left` and `position`. These are chosen to make it easy to generate both css code and a pdf. The `TemplateBlock` table also contains a column for `template_id`.

Next we have a `Moodboard` which has_many `Documents` through `MoodboardImages`

```
class Moodboard < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :documents, through: :moodboard_images
   has_many :moodboard_images, dependent: :destroy

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :moodboard_images

end
```

The `MoodboardImages` table contains one more column being `template_block_id` to determine the position in the `Template`

As it is now everything is working perfectly but i need validation on the `MoodboardImage` creation.
When saving a `Moodboard` with nested attributes for `MoodboardImages` there should be a restriction on the `MoodboardImage` for having the same `template_id`. a `Moodboard` can obviously not contain multiple templates.

My question to you guys is how can i accomplish this validation as neat as possible?

I can of course write a method that grabs the `TemplateBlock` from the database and store temporarily and compare it `before_save` or something but this is not pretty. I was wondering if there is a "nice" or "good" way to do this.

Comment: How does your `Moodboard` model look like? You can add the validations there, no?

Comment: The `Moodboard` model is not special, it has a name column only. The relations make the moodboard and i can add validation in the `Moodboard` model but it needs to query the new `MoodBoardImage`'s template_block_id to make sure the template_blocks all have the same template_id

Answer (score 0):

The validation would look like

```
validates :template_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :moodboard_id}
```

Refer to [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org)

Comment: The `template_id` does not live on the `MoodBoardImage` model, the template id needs to be retrieved from the associated `TemplateBlock` so in order for this to work rails needs to query the database for the associated block i think?